# Why am I receiving this error when trying to print folium map?

Tags: pandas, geospatial, geopandas, folium

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster

network1 = func_that_returns_osm("input")
    
map = folium.Map(location=[49.2949076,-123.0564621], zoom_start=9)
folium.GeoJson(data=gpd.GeoSeries(network1, crs="EPSG:4326"), style_function = lambda x: {'color': x['properties']['line_color']}).add_to(map)
map
```

The function that returns the OSM works fine. But I receive an error that states the following:
The truth value of a GeoDataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). I have read online that this usually pertains to truth values, but I don't see any truth values here?

Comment: I can only speculate since there is no data, but I suspect the error is that the geojson hierarchy is incorrectly specified and there are identical values that cannot be uniquely associated with the data.

Answer (score 0):

- I can replicate your error if `network1` is a **GeoDataFrame**
- if it is a **GeoDataFrame** there is not need to change it to be a **GeoSeries**
- additionally your code implies that the *geojson* associated with your geometry has a property *line_color* In place holder function I have coded, have also added this to make this code segment work

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
import osmnx as ox
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

def func_that_returns_osm(a):
    G = ox.graph_from_point(
        [49.2949076, -123.0564621], simplify=True, network_type="walk"
    )
    lines = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=True)[1]
    lines = lines.head(20).assign(line_color="red")
    return lines


network1 = func_that_returns_osm("input")

m = folium.Map(location=[49.2949076, -123.0564621], zoom_start=9)
# generates same error as in question
# folium.GeoJson(
#     data=gpd.GeoSeries(network1, crs="EPSG:4326"),
#     style_function=lambda x: {"color": x["properties"]["line_color"]},
# ).add_to(m)

# is network1 really a geopandas dataframe?  if so this works
folium.GeoJson(
    data=network1,
    style_function=lambda x: {"color": x["properties"]["line_color"]},
).add_to(m)

m
```